# The size of structure (sizeof) in C++ doesn't correspond the real size in case of arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, sizeof, memory-alignment

I use dynamic arrays of the following structure:

```
struct TestStructure
{
    unsigned int serial;
    int channel;
    int pedestal;
    int noise;
    int test;
};
```

The *sizeof(TestStructure)* returns 20, so I assume that there is no padding/alignment in the structure. It's logically because there are only 4-bytes types.

But I discovered that size of structure multiplied by element count is not equal the size of the array. There is an additional pad between elements of the array! So, in the following code:

```
TestStructure* test_struct = new TestStructure[element_count];
for (int i = 0; i < element_count; i++)
  FillStructure(test_struct, i, i, i, i, i, i); // assigning 'i' for all elements

Long_t size_value = element_count * sizeof(TestStructure);
unsigned char* p_value = new unsigned char[size_value];
memcpy(p_value, test_struct, size_value);
```

The output array of chars contains the additional pads between elements:

```
sizeof(TestStructure) = 20. element_count = 10. size_value = 200. char array in the hex format:
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
6c 6c 2f 6c

1 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 
6f 70 74 2f 

2 0 0 0 
...
```

Please, explain me.
Does dynamic array add pads between elements or
Does 'sizeof' operator show wrong size of the structure?

P.S. I use GCC 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2).

EDIT: I use this code in a macro with ROOT CINT interpreter with GCC compiled library. Sorrry, It seems this bug concerned not with GCC but with ROOT CINT.

EDIT2: Yes, in my ROOT macro (executed by CINT interpreter) *sizeof(TestStructure)* returns **24** and after that when I call a function of the GCC compiled library (containing the code fragment listed above), the *sizeof(TestStructure)* returns **20** in the compiled function.

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: If you use `std::vector` instead of dynamic arrays your quality of life will double [citation needed].

Comment: Either I didn't get you... or you did something wrong http://ideone.com/pBHZIQ

Comment: Post both the definition of `FillStructure` and your output code.

Comment: You can't do it with dynamic arrays either, not in a portable way. (and vector has a `data()` member func).

Comment: @KonstantinGertsenberger _" I can't do it with std::vector, that is why I use dynamic arrays "_ Huh?? What do you think a `std::vector` does actually?

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't use std:vector well because it doesn't normally support by ROOT CINT dictionaries but I'll try.

Comment: @KonstantinGertsenberger *Unfortunately, i can't use std:vector well because it doesn't normally support by ROOT CINT dictionaries* -- What is "ROOT CINT"?  Also if whatever "ROOT CINT" is requires a `T*`, then `std::vector::data()` returns the same `T*` that you would have gotten if you used `new[]`.  So I see no reason why vector cannot be used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although a compiler can add packing to the end of a `struct`,  a compiler absolutely **cannot** add additional packing between the elements when manufacturing an array.

For an array `TestStructure[n]`, the address of the i(th) element *must* be `TestStructure + i * sizeof TestStructure`. If this were not true then *pointer arithmetic* would break horribly.

Comment: Yes. Sorry. It seems this bug is concerned not with GCC compiler but with ROOT CINT interpreter which I use with GCC compiled libraries. I think the interpreter add packing to the end of the structure.

Comment: @KonstantinGertsenberger   This is the second question I'm seeing in two days that stems from the brokenness of CINT. I know nothing about CINT or ROOT, but CERN says they have [ditched CINT](https://root.cern.ch/cint) and perhaps you should too.